# Bytes to String or String to Bytes?

Tags: python, string, encoding, byte, screen-scraping

I have read some of the examples here but I am such a novice I don't understand some of them and others don't seem to work(probably because I'm such a novice but...

```
import urllib.request
import re
Symbols = ['aapl', 'spy' , 'goog' , 'nflx']
i = 0
while i < len(Symbols):
    Yahoo='http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=' + Symbols[i]
    htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(Yahoo)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    string = Symbols[i]
    symbol = string.encode('utf-8')
    pattern= re.compile(b'<span id="yfs_l84_'+ symbol +'">(.+?)</span>')
    price= re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
    print('The price of' + str(Symbols[i]) + ' is ' + str(price))
    i+=1
```

This doesn't work because in the `re.compile` statement I am trying to concatenate str and bytes.

I need to convert the string to bytes so that I can later iterate over a list of symbols and scrape the latest stock price from yahoo finance.

I have a feeling there is something wrong with my syntax there and the examples and python documentation has an argument for 'encoding' which I think is the 'utf-8' string but I don't really know.

Can someone help me with this?

Edit: I am using Bytes here because that is the only way it works, I get an error to change it to bytes if I don't (I am using 3.3).

The error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deaven And Teigan\Documents\Python Projects\YahooFinance.py", line 14, in <module>
    pattern= re.compile(b'<span id="yfs_l84_'+ symbol +'">(.+?)</span>')
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Comment: Why are you making the regex with a byte string? Also, please post the stack trace and exception with your question.

Comment: @Lattyware, TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Answer (score 1):

You should work with strings right up to the point where you actually want to make the network request rather than mix strings and bytes in your code. Generally eating, strings are the abstract representation of characters, whereas bytes are a specific encoding (e.g. Utf-8) of a string into a sequence of bytes that can be sent over a network.

Maybe you want to use a raw string for this line:

```
pattern= re.compile(b'<span id="yfs_l84_'+ symbol +'">(.+?)</span>')
```

Instead use

```
r'<span id="yfs_l84_'
```

Comment: This got me passed the error mentioned in intial question above. But I get a new error. price= re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\re.py", line 201, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: I think you will get a byes object when you read the data from the url request into the `htmltext` variable. You need to properly parse the response data into something more meaningful - e.g. you should check how the http response is encoded and then decode the bytes you get back into a string using that. Then you can do the regexp on the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

string = bytes( Symbols[i], 'Utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import re
Symbols = ['aapl', 'spy' , 'goog' , 'nflx']
i = 0
while i < len(Symbols):
Yahoo='http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=' + Symbols[i]
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(Yahoo)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
string = Symbols[i]
symbol = string.encode('utf-8')
pattern= re.compile(b'<span id="yfs_l84_'+ symbol +b'">(.+?)</span>')
price= re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
print('The price of' + str(Symbols[i]) + ' is ' + str(price))
i+=1


Hai try this it works
```

Comment: No it won't, mostly because you didn't indent properly.